# C 2D array of strings,strtol or atoi for returning int and histogram from that

Tags: c, string, dynamic-arrays, atoi, strtol

This is function for show how many times are some numbers in string,but 2D array dont work for me string is like a `Fift Evenue 45/01`
and in `hist_arr` must be on possition

```
0-1
1-1
2-
3-
4-1
5-1
6-
7-
8-
9-
```

```c
void funkcia_h(char **arr,int rows)
{
    int i,j,*his_arr;
    int input;
    long value;
    char *ptr;
    scanf("%d",&input);
    his_arr = (int *)calloc(10,sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            if(i == input)
            {
                value = strtol(arr[i][j],&ptr,10);//dont work
                value = atoi(arr[i][j]);//dont work
                if(value >= 0 && value <= 9)
                {
                    his_arr[value]++;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Note that `input` can be used uninitialized in your program, also you can do a `NULL` dereference, that is undefined behavior and it's bad.

Comment: char** aloc2D(int rows)
{
 int i;
 char **arr;
 
 if((arr=(char**)malloc(rows*sizeof(char*)))==NULL)
 {
  printf("Error\n");exit(1);
 }
 
 for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
 {
  arr[i] =(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
 }
 if(arr[i-1] == NULL)
 {
  printf("Error\n");exit(1);
 }
 return arr;
}

Comment: char ** funkcia_n(FILE *fr,int rows)
{
 int i,j;
 char **arr;
 
 otvor(&fr);//openfile
 
 arr = aloc2D(rows);

 for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
  for(j=0;j<20;j++)
   arr[i][j] = 'a';
 arr[3][14] = '5';
 zatvor(fr);//close file
 return arr;
}